# What does 「／＼」 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, classical-japanese, punctuation, symbols

皆さん、こんにちは！

Now, I've been reading 竹取物語 and have come across (another) set of symbols that I've yet to understand. Given the following sentence.

> かくて翁やう／＼豐になり行く。

What does the sudden 「／＼」 mean?

Comment: Could it possibly be the vertical iteration mark? See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark#Repeating_multiple_characters). By the definition in the wiki, I believe this sentence would then mean かくて翁やうやう豐になり行く。My Japanese is unfortunately too limited to parse this sentence though.

Comment: See this article about iteration marks in Japanese:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark#Japanese

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is supposed to be an iteration mark.

This type of iteration mark is usually only used in vertical writing (the traditional layout for Japanese writing). It looks like a big く but is twice as tall.

It also exists in Unicode, so I can try to produce it here, although it may not render nicely:

> や
>   う
>   〱

([Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B8%8A%E3%82%8A%E5%AD%97) does a better job and has more examples.)

The characters `／＼` are often (ab)used to represent the vertical iteration mark in horizontal writing.

So,

> やう／＼ = やうやう = ようよう = 漸う

Comment: ようよう？ Cool, thx lad! :D